# A function $f$ is differentiable in $[0,10]$ and $f(0)=4$ and $f(10)=-1.$If $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x+2}$ and $c\in(0,10)$,then find $g'(c).$

Tags: calculus

A function $f$ is differentiable in $[0,10]$ and $f(0)=4$ and $f(10)=-1.$If $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x+2}$ and $c\in(0,10)$,then find $g'(c).$

---

As $f$ is a differentiable function,so it satisfies Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem(LMVT).
I found $f'(c)=\frac{-1}{2}$ by LMVT.
$g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x+2}$
$(x+2)g(x)=f(x)$
Differentiating ,we get
$(x+2)g'(x)+g(x)=f'(x)$
So $(c+2)g'(c)+g(c)=f'(c)$
I am stuck here,I know $f'(c)$ but $c$ and $g(c)$ are unknown.I need that for finding $g'(c)$.

Comment: What is $c$? A particular element of $(0,10)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the regular mean value theorem.... $g'(c)=\frac{g(10)-g(0)}{10-0}=....$

Answer (score 0):

First, I enunciate the Mean Value Theorem for one real variable:

Let $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous and derivative functionn in $(a,b)$. Then, it exists $c\in (a,b)$ such that

$$f'(c)=\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

Your problem agrees all the conditions that the MVT imposes, so applying the expression:

$$g'(c)=\dfrac{g(b)-g(a)}{b-a}=\dfrac{\dfrac{f(b)}{b+2}-\dfrac{f(a)}{a+2}}{b-a}=\dfrac{\dfrac{f(10)}{10+2}-\dfrac{f(0)}{0+2}}{10-0}=\dfrac{\dfrac{-1}{12}-\dfrac{4}{2}}{10}=-\dfrac{5}{24}$$

And that's it.